# Remote to a computer that runs VPN?

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, remote

I want to connect via remote desktop to a computer and then open a VPN connection on that computer, but as soon as I turn the VPN on, I get disconnected from the remote computer. How can I remote to a computer and turn the VPN on at the same time?

Thanks in advance.
[network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNpcP.png)

Comment: Try using RDP with the IPv6 address of the remote computer. This might avoid the VPN breaking the RDP session.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunely, the answer I will give you won't be what you want to hear.

**PS!** *Don't turn off your computer, or your browser, there isn't a dead end yet(clarification if you read further).*

VPN stands for Virtual Private Network. It connects to a VPND host, and acts like it is that host.

VPN will terminate all the network processes including local network, and will connect them to that VPND network.

It means that the VPN will disconnect the Remote Desktop or other remote programs like ssh, and will reconnect it to the VPND network.

Tho...this isn't actually a dead end yet. There are VPNs that can customize which programs to use the VPN, for example Orbot for Android, so you should check if your VPN has this feature, or try finding VPNs with this feature.